# Keep JFrame on top of others

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am in a situation where I create a frame `FrameB` from my main frame `FrameA`. When the user is working on `FrameB` I would like it to be on top of `FrameA` even when the user accidentally clicks on `FrameA`.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have to use a JFrame?

If you use a JDialog instead of a JFrame and assign FrameA as the owner of the dialog through the constructor it will always remain on top of the frame. (Example: [How to set the JFrame as a parent to the JDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15429653/how-to-set-the-jframe-as-a-parent-to-the-jdialog/15430661#15430661))

Otherwise you can use setAlwaysOnTop() from the window class, but this can be dependent on the operating system/window manager.

Answer (score 3):

You could consider making FrameB a [JDialog](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) instead of JFrame, and set it modal.