# How to set the JFrame as a parent to the JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jframe, modal-dialog, jdialog

I am having trouble to set the frame as a owner to the dialog. Normally when I extend `JDialog` class for creating a dialog then I use `super(frame)` to specify the owner of the dialog such that both of them are not disjoint when you press `alt+tab`. But when I create a dialog using `new` like `JDialog dialog = new JDialog()` then I am unable to specify the frame as owner to the dialog.

Following example demonstrates above two approaches. `Top Click` button opens a dialog which is **without extending JDialog**. `Bottom Click` button opens a dialog **with extending JDialog**.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class DialogEx {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new DialogEx().createUI();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(r);
    }   

    private void createUI() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JButton button1 = new JButton("Top Click");
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Bottom Click");

        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                new DialogExtend(frame).createUI();
            }
        });

        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                new DialogWithoutExtend(frame).cretaUI();
            }
        });

        frame.setTitle("Test Dialog Instances.");
        frame.add(button1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(button2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class DialogExtend extends JDialog {
        private JFrame frame;
        public DialogExtend(JFrame frame) {
            super(frame);
            this.frame = frame;
        }

        public void createUI() {
            setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
            setTitle("Dialog created by extending JDialog class.");
            setSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
            setModal(true);
            setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    class DialogWithoutExtend {

        private JFrame frame;
        public DialogWithoutExtend(JFrame frame) {
            this.frame = frame;
        }

        public void cretaUI() {
            JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
            dialog.setTitle("Dialog created without extending JDialog class.");
            dialog.setSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
            dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
            dialog.setModal(true);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: actually looking (didn't run) at your code: what is the problem (except your unnessecary alias to frame in the extended)?

Comment: @kleopatra __extending JDialog is as bad as extending JFrame__ Exactly. That is the reason I want to know how can I make the frame as a owner to the dialog when I create a dialog using new.

Comment: using the constructor which takes the frame the same as when you extend it? Must be missing something ... please explain :-)

Comment: @kleopatra I have updated the code. Please look the class `DialogWithoutExtend ` which creates a dialog without extending the JDialog. Can you tell here how can I make the frame as the owner to this dialog.

Comment: again, still don't see it: what's wrong with ...  new JDialog(frame)?

Comment: haha .. so simple ... Thanks. Never tried this .. `new JDialog(frame)`?

Comment: @kleopatra If you don't mind can you please put your suggestion as an answer. Such that I can accept it.

Comment: +1 for [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @kleopatra I understand this is a stale thread - but why is it such a bad idea to extend JFrame (or JDialog)?

Comment: @ags Multiple inheritance is not supported in Java. Only if necessary we need to use extend class. In this scenario we can achieve the behaviour using Implements too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A dialog's (or window's) owner can be set *only* in the constructor, so the only way to set it is by using a constructor which takes the owner as parameter, like:

```
class DialogWithoutExtend {

    private JFrame frame;
    public DialogWithoutExtend(JFrame frame) {
        this.frame = frame;
    }

    public void cretaUI() {
        JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame);
        dialog.setTitle("Dialog created without extending JDialog class.");
        dialog.setSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
        dialog.setModal(true);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```