# Keep focus on a JDialog using SwingUtilities.invokeLater?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface, jdialog

I want to display a `JDialog` so I use this:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() { new DialogBox().setVisible(true); }
});
```

It works fine to display it but then my `JDialog` doesn't keep the focus, which it needs to (the user should not be able to work using the main UI while that dialog is open).

Is it safe to get rid of the `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`?

Oh and according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15429653/how-to-set-the-jframe-as-a-parent-to-the-jdialog) it is not wise to extend JDialog or JFrame, why? That's how I've always done it.

Comment: Don't you just want a modal dialog?

Comment: Extending a JDialog or JFrame comes down to design. What functionality are you actually adding to these top level containers? Here is also the consideration that if you build you UI directly on top of one of these top level containers, you are restricting the use of your UI components in the future. Better to extend something like JPanel, build your UI on top of this, providing the required accessors and place it ontop of an instance of the required top level container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It works fine to display it but then my JDialog doesn't keep the
>   focus, which it needs to (the user should not be able to work using
>   the main UI while that dialog is open).

have to [setModal(true)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setModal%28boolean%29) or [setModalityTypes(various types)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setModalityType%28java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType%29) for parent, or all windows from current JVM

```
Is it safe to get rid of the SwingUtilities.invokeLater()
```

yes exactly, all [Top-Level Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) should be created on [EDT, wrapped in invokeLater()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), including [JOptionPane](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12643642/714968)